# custom segue top bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, navigationbar

When I am creating a custom segue from one view controller to another, there's a problem with showing top bar properly.

This is the code for custom segue:

```
@implementation CustomSegue

- (void)perform {

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];

    destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         destinationViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
                         [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}

@end
```

I am using storyboard to set this up and sourceViewCotoller is embeded in NavigationViewController.

After performing a segue, there is no top bar in th destinationViewController.
I found an answer that I should add a Navigation Item to the destinationViewController - doesn't help. 
Another way of dealing with this that I found is embedding the destinationViewController in NavigationViewController. 
After doing this, the top bar is visible, but also during the segue. 
It's probably because I am adding the desitnationViewController into sourceViewController, so at the beginning of segue I have 2 top bars visible one below another.

How to deal with this ?

Comment: why you are using this statement [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

Comment: I found that way of doing this from a tutorial about custom segues. Removing this line does not fix the issue.

Comment: No i just wanna to know why that line is present